# TypeORM database is always empty after restart

Tags: typescript, typeorm, mysqljs

I just started using typeorm and ran into a major issue. Neither `conection.sychronize()` nor `repository.save(foo)` actually save changes to the database file. More precisly what is happening is that during runtine i can synchronize my db, save and read entities just fine. However when I close my program an run it again the db is empty. Not even the tables are present.

My entities

```
@Entity({name: "info"})
export class DBInfo {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column("integer", { name: "gameCreation", unique: true })
  gameCreation: number;

  @Column("integer", { name: "gameDuration"})
  gameDuration: number;

  @Column("integer", { name: "gameId", unique: true })
  gameId: number;
}

@Entity({name: "match"})
export class DBMatch {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => DBInfo, {cascade: true})
  @JoinColumn()
  info: DBInfo;
}
```

I open the connection like so

```
let connectionTemp: Connection;
try{
  connectionTemp = await createConnection({
    type: "sqljs",
    location: filePath,
    entities: [DBMatch, DBInfo],
    name: "MyConnection1"
  });
  console.log("DBReader", "connection open");
} catch (e){
  console.log("DBReader", "could not open connection", e);
}

return connectionTemp;
```

then I synchronize the database, creating all the tables:

```
await this.connection.synchronize(false);
```

writing entities to the db like this:

```
let savedMatch = await this.MatchRepositoryV5.save(dbMatch);
```

I left some parts of the code out becasue I think its unnecessary.

After that I can retrieve the match from the db, however when restarting my programm the db is completly empty again.
What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running this within Docker?

Comment: @AmbassadorKosh no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `autoSave` connection property to `true`

So you init the connection as following:

```
let connectionTemp: Connection;
try{
  connectionTemp = await createConnection({
    type: "sqljs",
    location: filePath,
    autoSave: true,
    entities: [DBMatch, DBInfo],
    name: "MyConnection1"
  });
  console.log("DBReader", "connection open");
} catch (e){
  console.log("DBReader", "could not open connection", e);
}

return connectionTemp;
```